# Julia BenchmarkTools output

Tags: julia

is it possible to save the histogram from BenchmarkTools (https://juliaci.github.io/BenchmarkTools.jl/stable/) into a file or plot for later visualization? It seems to display nicely when one works interactively but in batch mode, I haven't found an option to save this output histogram. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
julia> ben = @benchmark cos.(rand(4));
```

you could now seriaze ben `using Serialization` - just like any Julia object:

```
serialize("benchmark.ser", ben)

ben2 = deserialize("benchmark.ser")
```

Having this object you could and display it any time.

```
julia> ben2
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 10000 samples with 968 evaluations.
 Range (min … max):  75.413 ns … 724.587 ns  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 80.84%
 Time  (median):     81.921 ns               ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   89.433 ns ±  39.911 ns  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  2.05% ±  5.16%

  ▃▇█▆▄▃▁                                                      ▁
  ████████▇▆▆▅▄▅▅▇▇▆▆▅▆▅▄▅▄▄▅▃▆▄▃▅▆▄▅▄▅▅▄▆▅▄▄▄▄▄▅▆▆▆▆▅▅▄▅▄▃▃▂▃ █
  75.4 ns       Histogram: log(frequency) by time       244 ns <
```

You can save the ASCII art to a file:

```
open("bench.txt","w") do f
    show(f, "text/plain", ben)
end
```

This can be shown with any text editor or terminal that supports full Unicode set. You could also do `readlines("bench.txt")`,

Finally, the data is also available for plotting:

```
using Plots

Plots.histogram(ben2.times)
```